# How to create a candidate key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast 
(
      [Rot_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL ,
      [Rot_Code] [varchar](70) NOT NULL,
      [Menu_DT] int NOT NULL,   

      PRIMARY KEY ([Rot_ID], [Rot_Code])
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu_Dates_Mast] 
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1),
     [Menu_ID] AS ('DT' + RIGHT(('00000' + CONVERT(varchar, [ID])), 6)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
     [Menu_Cat] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
     [Menu_Modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
     [ROTATION][1](50) NOT NULL,   
     [Uplift_Id] [int] 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [AirCraft_Uplift_Mast]([UPLIFT_ID]),
     [Rot_Code] [varchar](70) 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast(Rot_Code)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm unable to create table `Menu_Dates_Mast` as I get this error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Menu_Date__Rot_C__15502E78'
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors

Kindly suggested the syntax to create `Menu_Dates_Mast` (table 2)

Comment: `Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast` defines a PK built from **two** columns - so any foreign key referencing it **must ALSO include** both columns. You cannot reference "half a PK" - it's an **all or nothing** proposition....

Comment: Any unique index is a candidate key, so you could add `CONSTRAINT ixU_Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast_Rot_Code UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Rot_Code])` to your Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast table definition.

Comment: In your table `Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast `, You would have a unique value with `[ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1)`. There isn't any reason to include `Rot_Code` in your primary key definition.

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason for having a combination of both Rot_ID and Rot_Code as a primary key?

I suggest redesigning your tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast 
(
    [Rot_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL ,
    [Rot_Code] [varchar](70) NOT NULL,
    [Menu_DT] int NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY ([Rot_ID])
 ) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu_Dates_Mast] 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Menu_ID] AS ('DT' + RIGHT(('00000' + CONVERT(varchar, [ID])), 6)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Menu_Cat] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Menu_Modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ROTATION][1](50) NOT NULL,   
    [Uplift_Id] [int] 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [AirCraft_Uplift_Mast]([UPLIFT_ID]),
    [Rot_ID] [int]
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast(Rot_ID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If that is not possible, and you still wish to reference Rot_Code column, you will have to make it unique in the parent table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Menu_Dates_Rot_Mast 
(
    [Rot_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL ,
    [Rot_Code] [varchar](70) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Menu_DT] int NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY ([Rot_ID], [Rot_Code])
) ON [PRIMARY]
```